# Cómo comparar string en Dart?

Tags: string, condiciones, dart

Intentando comparar un string que esta como objeto con una cadena de texto que el usuario ingresa, si el usuario ingresa como asesor se realiza la condicional if

```
String usuario= "asesor";
String nombre;

If ( nombre == usuario) {...}
```

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, recuerda que es importante no repetir preguntas en el sitio, revisa [ask] , y no olvides realizar el [tour] del sitio, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar el operador == de esta forma, el resultado de la comparación será `true` si ambos valores son iguales:

```
String  usuario= "asesor"; 
String nombre;

if (nombre == usuario) {
   print("iguales");
}
```

También puedes usar la función [**identical()**](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/identical.html) que comprueba si dos referencias son al mismo objeto en memoria.

```
   if (identical(nombre, usuario)) {
      print("iguales");
   }
```

---

Si vas a abrir una ventana diferente dependiendo del valor de usuario puedes usar también un `switch` que puede tener múltiples declaraciones condicionales dependiendo del valor de la variable `usuario`:

```
 switch(usuario) { 
   case "asesor": { 
      print('abre asesor'); 
   } 
   break; 
  
   case "noasesor": { 
      print('abre noasesor');
   } 
   break; 
      
   default: { 
      print('abre opción default');  
   }
   break; 
}
```

Comment: Para comparar el string con el nombre de usuario que se ha ingresado?

Comment: La idea es que dependiendo del nombre del usuario , lo direccione a diferentes ventanas, por ejemplo si ingresa como asesor, lo direcciona a una vemtana y si ingresa con un nombre diferente a asesor que lo direcciona a otra ventana diferente, como si fuera superusuario, por eso la pregunta de como comparar dos String, uno que ya esta definido como objeto  con otro que el usuario ingrese.

Comment: Ok @user203613 en este caso puedes usar if else pero te sugiero usar mejor un switch para definir multiples condiciones dependiendo del valor del nombre del usuario, revisa la actualización.

Comment: Por ejemplo asi:     switch(nombre) { 
   case "asesor": { 
     Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) =>
                  ListaChat()));
   
   } 
   break; 
   case "noasesor": { 
       Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => Chat(
               
                  )));
   } 
   break; 
      
   default: { 
      print('abre opción default');  
   }
   break; 
}

Comment: Entonces es posible implementar el switch en String , para ir verificando caso por caso?

Answer (score 0):

Como solo será un usuario en especifico el que tendra acceso a la ventana de ListaChat entonces seria asi,

````
     case "asesor":
       {
         Navigator.push(
             context,
             MaterialPageRoute(
                 builder: (context) =>
                     ListaChat()));
       }
break;

default:
       {
         Navigator.push(
             context,
             MaterialPageRoute(
                 builder: (context) => Chat()));
       }
       break;
   } ```
````

Comment: Hola, esto sería una respuesta?